# Anaconda Prompt virtual environment - 'python is not recognized...'

Tags: python, anaconda, virtualenv

I created and activated a virtual environment in Anaconda Prompt:

```
conda create --name test
activate test
```

When I try to run Python within this virtual environment, I get the following error:

> 'python' is not recognized as an internal or external comand, operable program or batch file.

Now, I understand that I'm missing Python in my `PATH` system variable, but why does it work outside of virtual environment while using Anaconda prompt?

Is there a better way to solve this (make Python work in Anaconda virtual environment) besides adding Python to `PATH` variable manually?

Comment: define what python you want to use in your env `conda create -n test python=3.7`

Comment: This worked. Fell free to add answer so I can mark as solved.